# How to rename line label in R autoplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, direct-labels

I have the following plot with true values (black line), fitted values (orange line) and forecasts (blue line).

If you notice on the right, the fitted values line says `NULL`. How can I change that to "Fitted Values"?. Also, why does it say "series on top"? How can I change that as well?

Here s my code:

```
data <- read.csv('C:/users/Datasets/Final Datasets/final_a.csv', TRUE, ",")
y <- msts(data$MeanTravelTimeSeconds, start=c(2016,1), seasonal.periods=c(7.009615384615385, 30.5, 91.3, 365.25))

fit <- tbats(y)
fc <- forecast(fit)

# Generating the plot:
autoplot(y) + autolayer(fitted(fit)) + autolayer(fc)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

````
autoplot(y) + 
  autolayer(fitted(fit)) + 
  autolayer(fc) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values="red", label="New Color Labsl", name="New Series Label") ```
````

`scale_colour_manual()` lets you change the colour and the attached label and the name applied to it.